# Using for loop to update the result from a container object

Tags: python, function, for-loop

I'm learning Python. Suppose you have the below function that returns the new dict 'd', but it instead returns the original unchanged dict. Does anyone have the correct code for this? (or is it something wrong with scope???)

```
>>> def ask():
...     d = {'b': 7, 'c': 3, 'a': 2}
...     for i, j in d.items():
...     

...             ans = int(input('the number for %s' %i))
...     

...             j *= ans 
...     

...     print(d.values())
... 
>>> ask()
the number for b3
the number for c235
the number for a432
dict_values([7, 3, 2])
```

Here's a similar function I created...

```
>>> def ask_for_input():
      d = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
      for i in d:
        ans = int(input('The number for %i' %i))
        i *= ans
      return d

>>> print(ask_for_input())
The number for 15
The number for 27
The number for 35345
The number for 474
The number for 53
The number for 6788
The number for 754
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>>>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Since your `j` is an integer it is a so-called immutable object in Python. This means that your in-place assignment doesn't really happen in-place. Instead `j` is rebound to the new value. Hence no side-effect on your dictionary.

Comment: So do i need to 'nonlocal' something? IDK how.

Comment: You need to explicitly assign to your dict: `d[i] *= ans`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @PaulPanzer told you, the problem here is `j`is rebound to a new value and not to the one in the dict anymore. The code that updates the value in the dict as you wanted, is this one:

```
def ask():
d = {'b': 7, 'c': 3, 'a': 2}
for i, j in d.items():    
    ans = int(input('the number for %s' %i))
    d[i] *= ans 
print(d.values())
```

Here, the values updated are the one in the dict.

I hope this could help you!